# How to access SAML Response after TAI and ACS have processed it during SSO

Tags: java, security, websphere, single-sign-on

I have developed a custom web application (WAR) that would need to retrieve the SAML response from request object and extract the user profile attributes from it. Deployed the same on WebSphere (Service Provider)

Trying to implement the below approach wherein::
-   OneLogin (Identity Provider) sends the SAML Response and Relay State
-   The SAML response is processed by the ACS application
-   The ACS application redirects the user to the custom web application (set in RelayState of IdP)
-   This application will then retrieve the SAML response object from request, populate the dynamic cache with user profile attributes and redirect the user to the main application home page .

Currently, the SAML response (once received and processed by WebSphere TAI and ACS application) does not seems to be available when the ACS redirects to the custom web application (set in Relay State). Is it possible to preserve and pass on the SAML response from ACS application to the custom web application?

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

**Warm Regards,**
*Ekansh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the original SamlResponse message in your application. However, it is possible to get the SAML Token (the SAML XML file) from application. Typically, one could use this SAML token to make web service call either over SOAP security header or Http header, or makes WS-Trust call to exchange SAML token for a new SAML token for downstream service call.
Can you make web service call (either JAX-WS or JAX-RS) instead of browser redirect? If web service call works for you, I can help you to make it working.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to extract the SAML attributes from SAML token in case User exists at both ends (IdP and SP). But what about the scenario when user does exists at SP end and needs to be created. In such a scenario, will the SAML token still be present even when ACS has unauthorized the access. Since, the user specific information (Ex: username, email etc.) are present in the SAML token, I will need the same to create a new user on the fly for such a scenario

Comment: WebSphere SAML SP has two configuration options. The default is that user does not have to exist in SP, and subject is created from the trusted SAML token. The other option is that user has to be in SP. If user is required to be in SP, and user is not in SP yet, we offer SPI for you to create user account before we create subject. To create user account, you implement com.ibm.wsspi.security.web.saml.NameIDMapping interface. In the implementation, you create user entry from SAML token if necessary. In TAI configuration, you use property to configure this SPI by adding sso_1.sp.userMapImpl=.

Comment: Thanks Chunlong. But I have question regarding this. Currently I am using  WAS 8.0.0.4. The "DEFAULT CONFIGURATION OPTION" which you have mentioned, is it "sso_<id>.sp.idMap"?

Comment: Tried setting the value of this property as "idAssertion" but am getting the below error (even though server is set to trust all realms - inbound)
WSCredentialT W   SECJ5008W: The realm specified in com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.realm (<my IdP URL>) does not match the current realm (defaultWIMFileBasedRealm). This could cause problems when trying to make a downstream request.

SECJ0129E: Authorization failed for user ekansh:my Idp URL while invoking GET on default_host:/wps/myportal/RightEverywhere, Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: All Role

Comment: W SECJ5008W is just a warning message, and it is not harmful.

Comment: And what about "E SECJ0129E" ?

Comment: This is relating to role mapping.  See the example Figure 19 in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1004_chao/1004_chao.html. If this does not resolve the problem, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Preserving and passing over the SAML response is meaningless. Essentially as the protocol defined , once the user is Authenticated @ OneLogin it sends back the SAML Token in the SAML Response to ACS . The ACS validates the SAML token and allows the user to proceed further .

Now if you are redirecting the user to the custom web application and would like to use SAML , then you should ideally implement a SAML service provider library in your application and your custom Web Application will act as another SAML Client , registered in OneLogin . The user in this case will get an SSO like experiance in case SSO is turned on at the Identity provider in this case OneLogin , since he has already authentication himself/herself when doing a login to ACS .

Comment: Thanks. I am able to extract the SAML attributes from SAML token in case User exists at both ends (IdP and SP). But what about the scenario when user does exists at SP end and needs to be created. In such a scenario, will the SAML token still be present even when ACS has unauthorized the access. Since, the user specific information (Ex: username, email etc.) are present in the SAML token, I will need the same to create a new user on the fly for such a scenario

Comment: I think you mean to say that user does not exists at SP but is present at IdP , in such a scenario yes your IdP will authenticate the user and will provide a valid SAML token to ACS , now it is upto ACS to decide if it needs to create the user on the Fly or ask him to to contact administrator or show him a failure . SAML has no role to play in this. If you think that my previous input has helped you in some way , please do not forget to mark it as Answer..

Comment: Thanks Soumen. The default Websphere ACS application seems to be marking the user as unauthorized. Therefore, in my application, when I am trying to get the subject and then, in turn the Set[] of SAML tokens from the subject (privateCredentials). It is returning an empty array [] . Is there any way for me to make the default ACS to still send the SAML token in this scenario.